# Extra content at the end of the document in google api in yii framework

Tags: php, yii

```
 <?php
 require("map_sql_db_info.php");


 // Start XML file, create parent node
 $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
 $node = $dom->createElement("markers");
 $parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ('localhost', $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}



 // Select all the rows in the markers table
   $query = "SELECT * FROM trk_route_location trl LEFT JOIN trk_location_master tlm ON          tlm.location_uid = trl.location_uid WHERE route_master_uid = '5'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
// ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
$marker = $dom->createElement("marker");
$node->appendChild($marker);
$marker->setAttribute("name",$row['location_name']);
$marker->setAttribute("address", $row['location_address']);
$marker->setAttribute("lat", $row['latitude']);
$marker->setAttribute("lng", $row['longitude']);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();

?>

// this is the controller code for yii

class MapallvehicleController extends Controller
{
//declaring the layout

public $layout = 'manage-users';

public function actionIndex()
{
    // including the hard coded scripts for the map view data

    require("hc_scripts/map_sql_xml.php");

    $this->render('index');
}
}
```

I am gettng this error in the browser

This page contains the following errors:

error on line 3 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

and this the output when i  do inspect  element in the browser-----

```
  <markers><parsererror xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: block; white-    space: pre; border: 2px solid #c77; padding: 0 1em 0 1em; margin: 1em; background-color: #fdd; color: black"><h3>This page contains the following errors:</h3><div style="font-family:monospace;font-size:12px">error on line 3 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
  </div><h3>Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.</h3></parsererror>   <marker name="Option Matrix" address="Mla colony banjara hills" lat="17.410692932084167" lng="78.42192220687866"/><marker name="Begumpet" address="Begumpet Colony " lat="17.442098234121936" lng="78.45804619789124"/><marker name="Venkatagiri Stop" address="Venkat giri" lat="17.4375" lng="78.4002"/><marker name="MLA Colony, Banjara Hills" address="Mla colony " lat="17.4101" lng="78.4205"/><marker name="Gulshan Colony" address="test address" lat="17.4003" lng="78.3947"/></markers>
```

Comment: What is the extra content?

Comment: Instead of inspect element, try view source. They are not the same :)

Comment: ya i checked view source also it the same as i posted.

but what is extra content I am not getting... please help!!!!.

Comment: i have also added the controller code for the yii framework plz check it out..

Answer (score 0):

In your **config/main.php**
 
comment this

```
    'log'=>array(
    'class'=>'CLogRouter',
    'routes'=>array(
    array('class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
    'levels'=>'error, warning',
    ),
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // comment this portion
   //  array(
   //  'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
   //  ),
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ),
    ),
```